# How to create a blog in ASP.NET and not ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, url, blogs

I have created a blog application with ASP.NET MVC and MSSQL. I must say, i really enjoyed the process of creating an application with ASP.NET MVC. Clean URLS(with URL routing), No view States and so on.

BUT i was wondering how would this would have been done if i choose web-form style coding? will the aspx would be created in the fly as i create a article.(take this url for ex: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/10/06/announcing-nupack-asp-net-mvc-3-beta-and-webmatrix-beta-2.aspx) though the URL is not clean but still makes sense. if yes then what about its corresponding cs file? if no how is the URL so clean?

Would be great if someone throw some light on how it is done in ASP.NET.

Thank you, Faraaz.

Comment: Is your question about "how to create a blog" or "how to have beautiful urls"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A blog in ASP .NET would have been done in much the same way. The idea is to use one file and URL rewriting. IIS7 has URL rewriting built in but for IIS6 you can use something like [ISAPI_Rewrite](http://www.helicontech.com/isapi_rewrite/) to handle .htaccess style files (which is what Apache uses).

ASP .NET MVC handles all this for you in its routing but you can do it yourself using a URL rewriting tool. The difference is that for MVC, the application handles the rewriting but ISAPI_Rewrite, IIS Rewriting are done by the server. This can change a URL like http://mysite.com/something/other to http://mysite.com/file.asp?p1=something&p2=other.

The second link is only internal to the server (it doesn't actually change the URL in the user's address bar). In the case of a URL like on Scott's blog, you could store the 'announcing-nupack-asp...' bit in a database as part of the article row so your blog article page has something to look for. The files don't actually exist on the server but the rewriting passes all requests to an existing file with parameters.

Note that this technique is common for lots of different sites - not just blogs. Notice the Stack Overflow URL, Twitter URLs, etc.

MSDN has an old article on [URL Rewriting in ASP .NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972974.aspx), along with some examples of filters you can use.

Comment: makes sense.. thanks much for the links. but, i see the IE Status bar displays rewritten URL when i hover to a URL in the blog. how is this done?

Answer (score 2):

If your using .NET 4, you can make use of `MapPageRoute` to accomplish the clean URL's with regular Web Forms.

```
routes.MapPageRoute("MySuperCleanRoute", "some/clean/url", "~/ActualPage.aspx");
```

With the addition of `MapPageRoute`, you no longer have the feeling "I should use ASP.NET MVC because i want clean URL's".

Choose ASP.NET MVC if you like the pattern. If your used to Web Forms, use it - and use `MapPageRoute` to achieve clean URL's (or use a URL Rewriting module if <= .NET 4)

Answer (score 0):

See [IIS URL Rewrite Module](http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the URL Rewriting that is in asp.net MVC with WebForms if you are using .Net Framework 3.5 SP1 (if you don't have access to .Net 4)

Here's an [MSDN magazine article explaning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd347546.aspx)...